# Django TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.datetime' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, database

When I try to add a new field or modify my model in any way I get the following error when I try to migrate to the database:

`File "C:\Users\uddin\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1913, in get_prep_value if value and ':' in value: TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.datetime' is not iterable`

This is what my model.py file looks like

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image




class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title2 = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    content2 = models.TextField(default=None)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics')
    post_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='post2_pics')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Full traceback of error**

[I've added the full traceback in a pastebin as not to make the post too long](https://pastebin.com/16aU7uiQ)

**front.0008_post_location file**

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.5 on 2021-03-06 01:21

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('front', '0007_post_content'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='post',
            name='location',
            field=models.GenericIPAddressField(default=django.utils.timezone.now),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show us an insertion example

Comment: Add the complete error traceback to your question.

Comment: Do you have or had a `GenericIPAddressField` anywhere in your models?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat in my views.py file I've created a view that uses a API to get the IP address of the user and displays the location there at, but there is no `GenericIPAddressField` in my models.

Comment: @MagaBeyworld please show the migration file `front.0008_post_location`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've added the file in the post

Comment: @MagaBeyworld As guessed at some point you had a field named `location` in your model to which you had added a `GenericIPAddressField` with `default=timezone.now`. The simplest solution would be to delete all migrations from this one onwards i.e. `front.0008_post_location` (note: if other apps have migrations depending on this one and ones later than that delete them too). After that run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat what would be the command to delete the migrations after the `front.0008_post_location`? or would I have to delete the whole **migrations** folder then run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: @MagaBeyworld Don't delete the whole migrations folder. Unfortunately you will have to delete them manually, if you don't have any important data in the database I would suggest that delete the database file and everything inside the migrations folder except `__init__.py`, otherwise if there is important data as I said above you would have to manually delete the relevant migrations. (Note: you can also use the solution by Kevin in his comment if you don't mind having some extra migrations that are unused. In fact it would be the simplest solution)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for your help!! You have no idea how much headache you've saved me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at some point you added a `GenericIPAddressField` named `location`, and gave as the `default` a callable that returns a `datetime`. Running the migration raises an exception since a `datetime` isn't a valid IP address.

When it didn't work, you just deleted the `location` field. The problem is that Django's migration system records a history of model changes, so removing it just created a new migration (when you ran `makemgirations`), keeping the bug forever enshrined in this migration file.

Next time, just fix the problem at the time and remove the buggy migration.

For now, you can simply edit the migration to make that line work. Since a later migration deletes the field, it doesn't really matter how you do that. I would simply replace the `default` with `null=True`.

Another option would be to use [`squashmigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing), which might (or might not) remove these redundant migrations that add and then remove a field. Or, if you're still at an early stage in your program, you can reset your migration history. There are various Stack Overflow questions on that subject.

Comment: I've added the file in the post. I don't quite remember using `GenericIPAddressField`. I know I created a field that was called `location` that was taking in the IP address using an API which I then deleted because it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! You have no idea how much headache you've saved me.